# How to terminate the program if execution time exceeds 30 min in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on a laravel application where the user uploads a book which then saves in my google drive.
I want to set a condition that if the time taken to upload a book has become 30 minutes then the program terminates and redirected back to upload page with message "file took too long to upload, try again or upload other file".
How can I do this.

I have two files,

1. showForm.blade.php having thr upload form with code

```
<!-- showForm.blade.php -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Upload File</title>
    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">

                <br><br><br>
                    <!-- store route as action -->
                    <form action="{{route('uploads')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    @csrf
                    
                    <!-- value Part -->
                    

                    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="thing" id="title">
                    <br>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-block btn-danger" value="Upload" onclick="spinner()">
                    </form>
                    @if (session('message'))
    <h1 id="t">{{ session('message') }}</h1>
@endif
     </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

2. web.php having routes which do all the uploading work

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    
    return view('showForm');
})->name("start");


Route::post('/upload', function (Request $request) {
        if($request->file("thing")=="") {
            // return back()->withInput();
            return redirect()->route('start')->with('message', 'Insert Data!');
        } else {
            $name=$request->file("thing")->getClientOriginalName();
            $book=DB::table('books')->where('Title',$name)->count();
            if($book>0) {
                return redirect()->route('start')->with('message', 'Document already exists!');
            } else {
                Storage::disk("google")->putFileAs("",$request->file("thing"),$name);
                $url=Storage::disk('google')->url($name);
                $details=Storage::disk("google")->getMetadata($name);
                $path=$details['path'];
                DB::insert('insert into books (Title, Url, FileId) values (?,?,?)', [$name,$url,$path]);
                return redirect()->route('start')->with('message', 'Successfully uploaded document, you have recieved token!');
            }
        }
    
})->name("upload");
```

Now I want to add a condition in web.php which checks if th execution time has become 30 min then run this code

```
return redirect()->route('start')->with('message', 'File took too long to upload, please try again or upload another file!');
```

Comment: try inside method ini_set('max_execution_time', $seconds);

Comment: How can I check the condition with this?